# Is zero in every ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $I \subseteq R$ be a subset of a ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ such that

- $(I, + )$ is a group
- $\forall x \in I, r \in R: xr \in I \text{ and } rx \in I$

Then $I$ is called an "Ideal"

**Question:** Is 0 in every ideal of any ring?

Comment: As long as you only deal with non-empty sets both of the properties you listed imply $0\in I$ even without each other.

Comment: @AlexJBest The property that $(I,+)$ is a group implies that $I$ is non-empty.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand that, I was just commenting to point out the (slightly cool) fact that if we assume non-emptiness of $I$ then the second property on its own implies $0\in I$ without the first being involved. It was just interesting that the statement follows from both of the properties listed individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$. What do you know about the identity of subgroups in relation to the containing group?

Answer (score -2):

the interesting thing is that 0 is always an ideal in any ring.
the second interesting thing is a ring is always ideal for itself 
meaning nothing is ideal for everybody 
and each one is ideal for  itself